# music completion handler in cocos2dx

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-x, simpleaudioengine

my goal is to call a function after background music ends in cocos2dx.

playing background music using this code

```
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic("shortSound.wav",false);
```

and need to call my Function

```
void GamePlay::gameLevelEnds()
```

when the background sound ends.

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct interfaces to do in cocos2dx but you can just find the duration of sound file and run an action with delay of duration followed by callback function.

Comment: and will that take app going to background and coming back to foreground in account?

Comment: Yes everything is paused, including actions.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

General Solution

```
float duration = 10.0f;
CCSequence *soundSequence = CCSequence::create(CCDelayTime::create(duration),CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(GamePlay::soundEndedAction)),NULL);
this->runAction(soundSequence);
```

method to monitor sound end action

```
void GamePlay::soundEndedAction(){
    CCLOG("+++sound ended+++%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

}
```

//======== For only iOS Platform below solution can be applied.=====//

I created a method in "AppController.h"

```
-(void)backgroundFinished;
```

and in  "AppController.mm"

```
-(void)backgroundFinished
{
    NSLog(@"+++Music ended....+++");
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->stopBackgroundMusic();
}
```

and added below lines in init method of "SimpleAudioEngine_objc.m" file

```
-(id) init
{
    if((self=[super init])) {
        am = [CDAudioManager sharedManager];
        //=======added this line=========//
        [am setBackgroundMusicCompletionListener:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] selector:@selector(backgroundFinished)];//28 Aug 2014
        //===============================//
        soundEngine = am.soundEngine;
        bufferManager = [[CDBufferManager alloc] initWithEngine:soundEngine];
        mute_ = NO;
        enabled_ = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

now in my "GamePlay.cpp" class I scheduled update method

```
void GamePlay::update(float dt)
{       
    if(!CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->isBackgroundMusicPlaying())
    {
        CCLOG("+++Background Music Ended+++ :%d",CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->isBackgroundMusicPlaying());
        //Take neccessory actions
    }
}
```